# Angular Validation: Input should either contain Latin or Georgian characters, but not both of them together

Tags: angular, regex, validation

This is my template for this part, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
(('^[\u10D0-\u10F0]+$')||('^[a-zA-Z]+$'))&&!(('^[\u10D0-\u10F0]+$')&&('^[a-zA-Z]+$'))
```

Also, it shouldn't contain any other characters or numbers, just Georgian or Latin.

Comment: Please provide the full relevant line(s) of code. I guess you are using `Validators.pattern` right?

Comment: Yes, I use those.
 firstName: ['',
        [Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.pattern('(('^[\u10D0-\u10F0]+$')||('^[a-zA-Z]+$'))&&!(('^[\u10D0-\u10F0]+$')&&('^[a-zA-Z]+$'))')]],

Obviously, this expression isn't correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
Validators.pattern(/^([a-zA-Z]+|[\u10D0-\u10F0]+)$/)
Validators.pattern('([a-zA-Z]+|[\\u10D0-\\u10F0]+)')
```

In the second line of code, as the regex is set with a string literal, `^` and `$` are added by Angular automatically.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-zA-Z]+|[\u10D0-\u10F0]+)` - Group 1 matching either one or more ASCII letters or one or more chars matched with `\u10D0-\u10F0` range (Gergian letters from `ა` to `ჰ`)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for your detailed explanation as well.